# dynamical width of div stacks

Tags: html, css

I have a stack of div boxes as follows:

[image]

My goal is: Box `B` and  `C` should be of the same width, and box `A` should be the width of `B` and `C`. The content of each box should be shown without line break. They should be arranged as in the picture. The content of box `A`,  `B` and `C` is created dynamically.

I almost achieved this (see code at bottom) by putting these 3 boxes in an `display:inline-block` and setting `width:50%` for box `B` and `C`. This works good in some cases, but when the content of box `B` is too large, I get this result:

[image]

I understand the outcome, since the total width is determined by box `A` and box `B` has `width: 50%`. However, I would like that box `B` gets stretched so that no line break is needed, like this:

[image]

How can I achieve this?

This is the code that produces the image (see this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4jv30o9v/)):

```
<style>
.container{
  display: inline-block;
  text-align:center;
  padding: 5px;
  border:dashed red;
}

.head{
  border:solid;
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 30px;
}



.item{
  width: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  border:solid;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 5px;
}

.red{
  background-color: red;
 }

 .green{
   background-color: green;
 }
}
</style>
<div class="container">
 <div class="head">
 A
 </div>

 <div>
   <div class="item red">
    B
   </div><!--
   --><div class="item green">
   C
   </div> 
 </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A minor change on structure and flexbox can do that.

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container {
  display: inline-flex;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
  border: dashed red;
  flex-wrap: wrap
}
.head {
  border: solid;
  background-color: yellow;
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  padding: 30px;
}
.item {
  width: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  border: solid;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 5px;
}
.red {
  background-color: red;
}
.green {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="head">
    Very very long text
  </div>


  <div class="item red">
    Also very very long text
  </div>
  <div class="item green">
    C
  </div>
</div>
```

Or...if you want the bottom divs wrapped...still flexbox

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container {
  display: inline-flex;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
  border: dashed red;
  flex-wrap: wrap
}
.head {
  border: solid;
  background-color: yellow;
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  padding: 30px;
}
.wrap {
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  display: flex;
}
.item {
  width: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  border: solid;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 5px;
}
.red {
  background-color: red;
}
.green {
  background-color: green;
}
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="head">
    Very very long text
  </div>

  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="item red">
      Also very very long text
    </div>
    <div class="item green">
      C
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```